# :hover state not reverting after jQuery UI "clip" animation - IE Bug

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, hover

Found a bug in IE (all versions), wondering if there is a workaround.

This is the bug in a very simple form using jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9frpL/6/

In Internet Explorer:

1. Click "show"
2. Click "hide"
3. Click "show" again

Notice how the "hide" link is still in its hovered state? Sometimes it doesn't happen if you move your mouse fast enough while the element is animating.

This bug doesn't happen with the "blind" UI animation or the basic slideUp() method, but the "clip" UI animation is really what I need for the project I'm working on.

Thanks for taking a look, hope you can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: Please check the below, even more uglier hack, [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9frpL/14/) here

```
$("#hide").bind('click', function(e) {

    $("#box").hide('clip', 'fast', function () {
        $('#hide').addClass('ieHax');    
    });
    e.preventDefault();

});

$('#hide').bind ('mouseenter', function (e) {
    $('#hide').removeClass('ieHax');
});
```

and CSS:

```
a.ieHax {
    color: #000 !important;
}
```

Original Ans:

One quick hack I could think of is to set the color to `#000` in `.hide` callback,

```
$("#box").hide('clip', 'fast', function () {
    $('#hide').css('color', '#000'); /* Hax for IE */
});
```

Pleas note that this is not a proper solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I might very well use it if nothing else comes along (even if it is a bit ugly!). I feel I'm going to struggle to find a solution as the issue is so specific to that "clip" animation.

Comment: Seems like this is the only solution, thanks. IE fails us once again. I changed the hack slightly, neatened up the CSS. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9frpL/25/